# relation of supp of form $\omega$ and $d\omega$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given $n$ dimension smooth manifold,and smooth $k$ (where $k\le n-1$) form $\omega$.

Assume we know $\text{supp}\ \omega \subset U$ where $U$ is open subset of $M$

Can we say anything about support for $\omega$ and $d\omega$,for example the proporsitions below is true or false:

> 1. $\text{supp} (d\omega) = \text{supp}(\omega)$
> 2. $\text{supp}(d\omega) \subset \text{supp}(\omega)$

(I try to show for example when $\omega$ is 0-form,and $\text{supp}(d\omega)\subset \text{supp}\omega\ $ i.e. denote $Z(\omega) = \{p:\omega_p \ne 0\}$ it's sufficient to show $Z(d\omega) \subset Z(\omega)$ but we can't say if $\omega_p =0$ then $(d\omega)_p = 0$ ?since $(d\omega)_p(X_p)$ is determined by the neighborhood value of $\omega$ around $p$ not only a single point?

Comment: Hint: Can you show that $\operatorname{supp}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\subseteq\operatorname{supp}f$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: No there is no relation between them.

Comment: There is: If $x\notin\operatorname{supp}(f)$, then $f|_U=0$ for some open neighborhood $U\ni x$. It follows that $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right|_{U}=0$ as well.

Comment: but $Z(d\omega) \subset Z(\omega)$ does not hold in general correct?

Comment: It does not hold in general.

Comment: The relevant inclusion is the compliment of the supports, in reverse order .$$\operatorname{int}(Z(\omega))\subseteq\operatorname{int}(Z(d\omega))$$

Comment: @yi_li: Note that $\operatorname{int}(Z(\omega))$ is open, so if $p \in \operatorname{int}(Z(\omega))$ then there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ such that $V \subseteq \operatorname{int}(Z(\omega))$, i.e. $\omega|_V \equiv 0$.

Comment: Oh ...thank you.I made a mistake on notation,so,that's why I can't figure it out $Z(\omega) = \{p:\omega_p \ne 0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument similar to the one mentioned by Kajelad in the comments above.

We show that the exterior derivative $d:\Omega^k(M)\to \Omega^{k+1}(M)$ decreases support in that $\operatorname{supp}(d \omega)\subseteq \operatorname{supp}(\omega)$.

> Proof: Suppose $p\not\in \operatorname{supp}(\omega)$. Then there exists an open set $U\ni p$ such that $\omega|_U\equiv0$. So, for any $q\in U$, $(d\omega)_q=0$ and therefore $p\not\in \operatorname{supp}(d\omega)$. I.e. $\operatorname{supp}(\omega)^c\subseteq \operatorname{supp}(d\omega)^c$ and hence $\operatorname{supp}(d\omega)\subseteq \operatorname{supp}(\omega)$.

In the above argument, we used that if $\omega|_U\equiv 0$, then viewing it in local coordinates as
$$\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_k}f_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots dx^{i_k}$$
we must have $f_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}(q)=0$ for all $q\in U$. Hence, because $f_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}$ are constant in $U$ their partial derivatives vanish. I.e. $(d\omega)|_U\equiv 0$. By the way, this also allows you to construct a counterexample where the containment is strict. For instance, take $f\in \Omega^0(\Bbb{R})$ which is constantly equal to $1$. $df\equiv 0$.

You can also modify this to get an example for compactly supported forms, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: For the argument above we can also use pull back commute with derivative to show it that is $d(\omega)|_U = d(\omega|_U) = d(0) = 0$

Comment: For the compact support form,once it has a flat "platform" the containment is strict.

Comment: Yes and yes. ${}$